# second case Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The values are stored in varchar.I try to check if the values are numeric then convert to decimal, if not then return the original value.
The first case itself work fine if I comment out the second part.

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Num) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),CONVERT(FLOAT, Num))
     WHEN ISNUMERIC(Num) = 0 THEN Num END,
```

Comment: The result of that `CASE` expression can be different data types, that can't be

Comment: doesn't the first one return an error on `isnumeri`?

Comment: To xQbert, I accidently delete the c...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning different types. You need convert the return values to the same type for safe query. Either convert the decimal back to varchar, or return 0 when num is not a number.